# Error converting data type bigint to varchar.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @ID BIGINT
set @ID = 1323
UPDATE School 
SET RegistrationFee = 'fee_' + @ID --<<<<error 
Where SchoolRegistrationId = 123
```

Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to explicitly convert your bigint to varchar:

```
DECLARE @ID BIGINT
set @ID = 1323

UPDATE School 
SET RegistrationFee = 'fee_' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(15)) 
WHERE SchoolRegistrationId = 123
```

T-SQL will not do this automatically for you - you need to be explicit and clear about it.

Answer (score 6):

You can't concatenate a string to a number.  You have to convert it:

`SET RegistrationFee = 'fee_' + LTRIM(STR(@ID))`

Comment: STR won't work with BIGINIT for huge numbers, they appear as '***********'. I ended up using CAST(myField as VARCHAR(25)).

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server automatically converts the data from one data type to another. This is Implicit conversion. Your script has a process with diffirent types (varchar and bigint). Bigint is an exact numeric type. 
"Character expressions that are being converted to an exact numeric data type must consist of digits, a decimal point, and an optional plus (+) or minus (-). Leading blanks are ignored. Comma separators, such as the thousands separator in 123,456.00, are not allowed in the string."
(see. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine link.)

You should use explicit convertion to force It doesn't occur implicit convertion automaticly. Such as CAST function.

Choose one depend on RegistrationFee column data type in following expressions.

```
'fee_' + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(25)) 
'fee_' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(25)) 
'fee_' + CAST(@ID AS CHAR(25)) 
'fee_' + CAST(@ID AS NCHAR(25))
```

-- Bigint max value is '9,223,372,036,854,775,807'  that has 25 chars.

Answer (score 1):

It is a string of 20 characters in length (sign + 19 digits) since a bigint value does not have formatting.

```
DECLARE @b AS bigint = -9223372036854775807
SELECT CAST(@b AS varchar(20)) AS [Text]
```

Anything above 20 is excess.